# Partial ASP.net deployment issue - "Could not load assembly "App_Web_xxx.dll", make sure that it is compiled before accessing the page"

Tags: asp.net, web-deployment, dllimport

I am using Visual Studio 2017, and the application target .net framework is 4.5.2.

This application ABC (to which I am providing an enhancement) is already deployed and functioning pretty well.

Now that I have to only perform changes on 1 page (a simple condition change), I am planning to deploy only App_Web_xxxx in the ".\bin" folder.

After publishing the application using the "Precompiled" configuration, I was able to identify the respective App_web_xxx.dll file and copied in App. Server bin folder. Renamed it according to existing requestEdit.aspx file. All looks good till now, and interestingly, this App_Web_xxx.dll is common for multiple aspx files available under a common folder (users/request).

Once I try executing this code by accessing the website (respective aspx.cs UI file), it gives the error:
"Could not load assembly "App_Web_xxx.dll", make sure that it is compiled before accessing the page".

But the issue is This dll file doesn't break for any other aspx page available under the User/request folder, it is failing only for feature I modified.

What I have done apart from above mentioned way (considering usual way of partial deployment process):

1. Replaced requestEdit.aspx page and added new dll, by keeping old dll as is (which can be used by other aspx pages in deployment folder)
   Error changed to:
   Could not load assembly 'App_Web_xxx.dll, version=0.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, Publickey Token=null' or one of its dependencies.The system cannot find the file specified.
2. Replaced requestEdit.aspx page and added new dll, by removing old dll and renaming App_Web_xxx.dll in "Imports = Default.aspx, App_Web_xxx.dll" in all required aspx files (for which the old dll was removed)

If I am replacing the whole solution (except web.config) the solution works fine with no issues, the only problem comes when I am replacing only 1 .dll file.

All the solutions I found are providing information of IIS version or dll copying from Server to Dev, but my problem is I'm publishing on dev env (local machine) and partially deploying on the server.

Need help to resolve this issue as this is really inconvenient to deploy the whole solution just for 1 condition change!

Additional Info:
Page Properties --> MSBuild Options --> Allow this Precompiled site to be updatable (checked)